# C# StreamReader(string path) - Is the path accessible again somehow?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I've an implementation of StreamReader.

```
internal class MyStreamReader : StreamReader
{
    public MyStreamReader (string path) : base(path)
    {
    }
```

The argument is a path to a file.

I wanted to throw an exception and include the complete filename in its message. I know of course that I could easily save it in a field of my own class like "_path" but I wanted to make sure that I don't do anything redundant. Am I somehow able to access the "path" argument again?

Edit since there seems to be some confusion:

```
throw new FileLoadException($"Corrupt source file! File '{ // I need something to represents the file with its path }' is malformed. (...)");
```

So, is `// I need something to represent the file with its path` easily replaceable without adding a field `_path` to my class. Something like `this.GetTheInConstructorArgumentedPath()`.

Comment: Class Exception has field Data where you can add name-value pair and then get it.

Comment: Instead of using `Exception` base class - create your own `WrongFileNameException` which inherit from `Exception` and add there any data you want. It will give you more detailed information about thrown exception. And you can catch that exception by `catch (WrongfileNameException)`

Comment: @Fabio That's absolutely not what I've asked for. I'm going to clarify this.

Comment: If you going to throw exception somewhere else outside of constructor, then you need to save  it in the local variable.

Comment: @Fabio Heck, I've mentioned twice that I'm aware of this. :) I just wanted to make sure not to do something redundant since I couldn't believe that StreamReader doesn't provide a method out of the box.

Comment: Why is it `something redundant` ?

Comment: @ColinM Because the underlying base class may (and as the accepted answer proves does) hold the information accessible already. A value like this is unlikely to be completely private.

Comment: StreamReader is not based on paths but on streams. The path ctor is a convenience method. It forgets the path after converting it to a stream. Extracting the path from BaseStream is relying on implementation details. It will probably work forever but it's not good style. I'd store the path explicitly if I was you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting BaseStream to FileStream and get name from it (if you think it is always a file stream you use).

```
(this.BaseStream as FileStream).Name
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I've added a nullcheck:            var fileStream = this.BaseStream as FileStream;
            if (fileStream != null)